# How to create generic TemplateRef and then pass it to the other component as object param?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ng-template

I have such a problem: I receive data from api and then generate neccesery data based on it. One of the parameters that I have to pass to my own grid component is the `TemplateRef` type based on specific data. The problem is that there is possible to have many records so I need to make `TemplateRef` for each of them.

So in the html I have example template:

```
<ng-template #someTemplate>
 <app-some-component [param1]=... [param2]=...></app-some-component>  <- params depends on received data
</ng-template>
```

And in the component I have:

```
@ViewChild('someTemplate', {static: true}) someTemplateContent: TemplateRef<any>;
```

So basically I want to create `someTemplateContent` for each object of data array and then pass it as object param. How could I do this? Do I need to change something in the template? I meam use `ngFor` over the template?

Comment: what are `[param1]=... [param2]=` represent? are they going to be the same for all the record? if not are they properties of object within an array?

Comment: These are inputs, will be different for each of records

Comment: are they stored within an array of records?